# Local Storage is not shared between pages

Tags: javascript, html, epub, epub3

I have an epub3 book with 2 pages as well as a Table of Contents Page. I am viewing this book in Apple's Books, their inbuilt epub3 reader, on Mac OSX. The two pages appear side by side. The first page is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, height=600"/>
    </head>
    <body>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
  var current_page = "1";
  var other_page = "2";

  var t = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    var d = new Date();
    var storage = localStorage; 

    storage.setItem("t"+ current_page, d.toLocaleString());

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = storage.getItem("t"+ current_page) +" "+storage.getItem("t"+ other_page);    
  }, 1000);

//]]>
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the only thing different in my second page is:

```
  var current_page = "2";
  var other_page = "1";
```

So every second, Page 1 saves the current time to Local Storage as `t1`, and Page 2 does the same for the value `t2`. At the same time, both pages are reading both `t1` and `t2` from Local Storage, before their values are displayed to screen. However in ibooks, Page 1 only manages to display the current value for `t2` when the page is reloaded - like when I flip to the Table of Contents and then back to Page 1 and 2 again. With something similar happening for Page 2 with regard to `t1`.

So at time 21:10:00, Page 1 might display:

08/09/19, 21:09:18       08/09/19, 21:08:58

and Page 2:

08/09/19, 21:09:22       08/09/19, 21:08:01

I also tried using Session Data but Page 1 can't ever read `t2` and Page 2 can't read `t1`. So, this would be displayed instead:

08/09/19, 21:09:18       null

I can think of several applications where it would be very useful for Pages to communicate with each other.

For example, if a video is playing on one page, it would be useful to stop it if a video on another page is started. This would normally be done using Session Storage. This is related to my own use case and the reason I started exploring this problem.

Likewise, if the user is asked on Page 1 to enters the name of the main character of the story, then that entry should appear immediately on Page 2 once it is entered.

Is there any other way for Pages to communicate with each other in epub3 other than Local or Session Storage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do two web pages have different localStorage? How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709523/why-do-two-web-pages-have-different-localstorage-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: Be careful about same origin for local storage. how do you serve your pages? From a web server or with file:// protocol?

Comment: @Laurent T I am serving them using Books which is an inbuilt ebook reader for Mac. The pages are contained within the same epub file.

Comment: @Baz according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552474/ibooks-is-it-possible-to-use-localstorage-when-importing-a-epub-file it seems that localstorage has been disabled?

Comment: There is API for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API, unfortunately it is very poorly supported yet https://caniuse.com/#feat=broadcastchannel

Comment: it seems you are looking for some kind of parallelism, to execute scripts on page 1 and at the same time on page 2. I guess for performance and any other reason only 1 page is active at a time and running scripts. you can try to check this only displaying the current time on both pages at the same time.

Comment: You could also use [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know `epub3` and dont have a MAC to test, but here are four possible solutions that come to my mind:

## Cookies

It is not as performant as `localStorage` for that use-case, but if you dont have many options, better that than nothing.

Functions to create, read and delete cookies (Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230846/9150652):

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

Usage for your example:

```html
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  var current_page = "1";
  var other_page = "2";

  var t = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    var d = new Date();

    setCookie("t"+ current_page, d.toLocaleString(), 100); // 100 days

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getCookie("t"+ current_page) +" "+getCookie("t"+ other_page);    
  }, 1000);

//]]>
</script>
```

## BroadcastChannel

BroadcastChannel is a very new functionality, so it might not be supported by the "Books" app. But here is a concept:

```html
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  var broadcaster = new BroadcastChannel('test');
  var current_page = "1";
  var other_page = "2";

  var t = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    var d = new Date();

    // Send message to all other tabs with BroadcastChannel('test')
    bc.postMessage({
        senderPage: "t"+ current_page,
        date: d.toLocaleString()
    });
  }, 1000);

  broadcaster.onmessage = (result) => {
      if(result.senderPage == "t"+ other_page) { // If the message is from the other page
        // Set HTML to current date + sent Date from other page
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString() +" "+result.date;    
      }
  };

//]]>
</script>
```

## Some sort of Backend

If none of the above works, you probably have no other option, than to use some sort of backend, to provide and save the data

If it is just for you, I suggest you to use a free tier of Firebase or MongoDB Atlas, as they both provide quite some value on their free tier.

If you do it with a Backend, it could be done with something like this:

```html
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  var current_page = "1";
  var other_page = "2";
  var lastLocalDate = new Date();
  const serverUrl = "http://someUrl.com/endpoint/"

  // Gets the latest date of the other page via ajax
  function getUpdate() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            // If successful, update HTML
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = lastLocalDate.toLocaleString() +" "+xhr.responseText;
            }

            // Update the date of this page anyways
            sendUpdate();
        }
    };

    // GET request with parameter requestingPage, which is the other page
    xmlhttp.open("GET", serverUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.send(`requestingPage=${other_page}`);
  }

  // Sends the current date of this page to the webserver
  function sendUpdate() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // No need to check if successful, just update the page again
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            getUpdate();
        }
    };

    lastLocalDate = new Date();

    // POST request with parameters page and date
    xmlhttp.open("POST", serverUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.send(`sendingPage=${current_page}&data=${lastLocalDate.toLocaleString()}`);
  }

  // Start with sending an update (so that lastLocalDate is at least sent once to the server)
  sendUpdate();
//]]>
</script>
```

And some methods in your backend that need to look something like this (note that this is not valid code in any language):

```
@GET
function getDate(requestingPageId)
    find latest entry with page.id == requestingPageId
    return page.date

@POST
function saveDate(savingPage, savingDate)
    store new page element with 
        page.id = savingPage
        page.date = savingDate
```

And a collection in your database looking like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        date: "date"
    },{
        id: 2,
        date: "date"
    },{
        id: 2,
        date: "date"
    },{
        id: 1,
        date: "date"
    },

    // ...
]
```

## Window References

If the Books app opens the second tab from the first tab, it might be worth to look into:

- [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

  - With its functions:
  - [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
     to open the second tab and get a reference to it
  - And [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) to get a reference to the opener